# How to use modal verbs in the past tense speaking of future possibility?

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, future-time

everyone.

I learn English vocabulary and write sentences about my life using new words. But I have a problem. I can't write one sentence so that both grammar and meaning are correct.

Some context to understand what I mean:

1) I want to say that in the future I'll have a business.

2) But also I want to add a type of business which I can't say exactly so I can only guess that it's not something like a small shop or cafe. I want to add some possibility of what type of business I would set up.

If I say it in the present, I'll say like "it might be a big company" or "it mightn't be something like a cafe".

But I write about what I thought in the past.

So, I write my past story and want to say that I had some future possibility of setting up a business in the past.

I think I should use modal verbs to express possibility but how I can use them in the past tense speaking of the future time.

Comment: "I used to think that one day I would set up my own business, possibly X but not Y."

Comment: Thank you very much for your answering. It looks very well. I was thinking of using "would", but it seemed to me that it would be wrong. What does the word "would" mean in your example? Is there just speaking of the future? I understand that your sentence is grammatically correct but there is another option to join meanings of the words "would" and "possibly" to use one single word?

Comment: "I want to say that in the future I'll have a business." _I'll_ means _I will_, so describing those plans as being made in the past it becomes _I would have a business_. Ideas about what kind of business it was going to be need to be in a new phrase. I can't see any other way of expressing it.

Comment: I think your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

> At that time, I was thinking that I *might* one day start a business. It *wouldn't* be something like a small cafe though.

You had asked "is there another option to join meanings of the words "would" and "possibly" to use one single word?"

Yes, "might" does that.

More details:

- Don't use "mightn't". It's not common usage. Rather, say "might not".
- Which part is certain, and which part is uncertain? In the example sentence I wrote, starting a business is *possible*. It is *uncertain*.  So, "might" was added. However, what is *certain* is that if the business proceeds, it won't be a small cafe. So, "wouldn't" was added. This seems like a reasonable set of assumptions.  However, if there is a chance that it *might* be a cafe after all, then it should be switched from negative to positive, removing "not".

> "It  *might* even be a cafe, although I doubt it."

---

Unless... there is a strong assumption by the listener that it's going to be a cafe. Then you could say

> "It *might not* be a cafe though."